# Oracle SQL to find entries matching two conditions in one table

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, having

I have a table in an Oracle database which contains

| Object | Extension_key | Extension_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | IpAddress | 1.2.3.4 |
| AAA | Userid | User1 |
| AAA | DownloadDirectory | /homeA |
| BBB | IpAddress | 1.2.3.4 |
| BBB | Userid | User2 |
| BBB | DownloadDirectory | /homeB |
| CCC | IpAddress | 5.6.7.8 |
| CCC | Userid | User3 |
| CCC | DownloadDirectory | /homeC |
| DDD | IpAddress | 1.2.3.4 |
| DDD | Userid | User1 |
| DDD | DownloadDirectory | /homeD |

What is the query that would find all of the Object entries when IPAddress is 1.2.3.4 and Userid is User1 ?

Comment: Hi - as this is not a free code writing service, what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select object
from mytable
where (extension_key, extension_value) in ( ('IpAddress', '1.2.3.4'), ('Userid', 'User1') )
group by object
having count(*) = 2
```

The idea is to filter the table for the two key/value tuples that you are interested in; the we aggregate by object, and retain only objects that matched on both predicates.

Note that this assumes no duplicates in the table - otherwise we would need `distinct` in the `having` clause:

```
having count(distinct extension_key) = 2
```